# Performance: WHERE IN clause vs (INSERT + INNER JOIN)

Tags: sql, database, performance, join, where-clause

I have a use-case where I need to perform a very high number of SELECT SQL

I have two approaches at this moment:

1. Query by a list of identifiers. So, I first used WHERE IN clause:

   - *SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4
     FROM MAIN_TABLE 
     WHERE COL1 IN ( 1,2,3,8,11,78,59,65,74,25,36,54558,78854,558 )*
2. I can create a table, let's say, CACHE_TABLE, and first INSERT the identifiers ( 1,2,3,8,11,78,59,65,74,25,36,54558,78854,558 ) into it by a unique key CACHEID and the JOIN this CACHE_TABLE with MAIN_TABLE to get the desired result:

   - *SELECT MT.COL1, MT.COL2, MT.COL3, MT.COL4
     FROM MAIN_TABLE MT
     JOIN CACHE_TABLE CT
     ON CT.IDENTIFIER = MT.COL1
     WHERE CT.CACHEID =*

Performance is really critical in my use-case. So I wanted to know if the approach #2 would yield better performance than approach #1.
Also, if there is a better alternative approach(s) for this

Thanks a ton in Advance!!

Comment: Have you tried running either of those queries with the Execution Plan displayed?

Comment: Provided you have indexes a join should perform good. There are basically 3 types of doing that: Where exists (...), where col in (...) and join. You should test which one is better. It might be different for low density and high density cases. (Some backends internally convert in (...) to a OR query)

Answer (score 0):

your answer is best performance approach #2. 
In my experience IN is a very slow operator, since SQL normally evaluates it as a series of WHERE clauses separated by "OR" (WHERE x=Y OR x=Z OR...).  As with ALL THINGS SQL though, your mileage may vary. The speed will depend a lot on indexes

Comment: Hello Alireza, thanks for your input! Can you please tell me why would approach#2 win? Thanks

Comment: .In my experience IN is a very slow operator, since SQL normally evaluates it as a series of WHERE clauses separated by "OR" (WHERE x=Y OR x=Z OR...).  As with ALL THINGS SQL though, your mileage may vary. The speed will depend a lot on indexes

Answer (score 0):

You need to test the two approaches.

For a single query, I would expect `in` to win in most cases -- simply because creating the table and then uses it requires multiple round-trips to the database.

In addition, some databases optimize constant lists (for instance, MySQL does a binary search on values rather than a sequential search).

The one thing that will help either version is an index on `(col1)` or `(col1, col2, col3, col4)`.

Comment: Hello @Gordon, Thanks for your input. Just a comment or doubt, the CACHE_Table will already be present, we will do Insert and Join only. Also, there are good chances the IN query would have more have 70-100 keys in every select. Could you please advice, if approach #1 is still better?

Comment: @RajMansinka . . . I'm going to repeat that you need to test on your database.  More important is the index on your main table.